# What event to hook to redirect on 404 errors? Symfony 1.4

Tags: redirect, symfony1, event-handling, symfony-1.4

I am using symfony 1.4.

I need to redirect certain urls when 404 error occurs.
Let's say user is looking for a url http://example.com/oldurl and it doesn't exist I want to check if this url is set for redirect.
If url is set to be redirected I would like to redirect it to that url.

QUESTION: Which event should I hook into to get info about the requested url, that got redirected to 404 error page ?

P.S We only want to check for redirection if page doesn't exist. We do not want to run "the check" for every request, only when page not found!

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony fire an event each time a page is not found: `controller.page_not_found`.

You can find it in the documentation: http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/15-Events#chapter_15_sub_controller_page_not_found

**Edit:**

You can retrieve the url in the method that listen to this event by calling the context. With something like that:

```
$context = sfContext::hasInstance() ? sfContext::getInstance() : null;
if(null !== $context)
{
  $requested_url = $context->getRequest()->getUri();
}
```

You can give a closer look to the plugin [sfErrorNotifierPlugin](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfErrorNotifierPlugin/trunk), it catches exception and 404 error and send an email for a report. Look at [how they handle 404 error](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfErrorNotifierPlugin/trunk/lib/sfErrorNotifier.php#L26).

Comment: @jOk you missed "...get info about the requested url..." part. Any idea how on "controller.page_not_found" hook to obtain the requested url?

Comment: Nice plugin, should have googled first because I actually implement the same thing a month ago.

Comment: @mhitza there is an other plugin more decoupled/complex: [fpErrorNotifierPlugin](https://github.com/makasim/fpErrorNotifierPlugin)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where to hook exactly inside the execution stack, but I know the general cleaner way through routing. If you are doing routing without still having in code the default routing rule (which you shouldn't by practice since), then it would be as simple as the following in your app `routing.yml` (at the end):

```
catch_all:
  url: /*
  param: { module: yourModule, action: handleNotFound }
```

Comment: This is something we would like to avoid, we only would like to check if there is a redirect rule for certain url if ONLY page not found.

Comment: We do not want to run a check on every request, this will hurt the performance!

Comment: I think you misunderstand the routing part of symfony. This placed at the bottom of the routing will match when no other did, thus only for 404 pages.

Comment: Modules in earlier routes also redirect to 404. For example: if product not found then 404error showed. Thought I have to check it out!